# Obter informação guardada em um "attribute"

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão, atributos

No ORM que utilizo, as classes são mapeadas usando `Attributes`. Eu preciso recuperar o valor armazenado nos mesmos. Ex.:

```
[Table("CADASTRO_CLIENTE")]
public class Cliente
{
    [Property("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Exemplo de uso (fictício - é isso que eu preciso saber)

```
var nomeTabela = Cliente.GetTableName();
//nomeTabela seria "CADASTRO_CLIENTE"
```

---

Estou usando NHibernate com ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer o seguinte:

```
public static string GetTableName()
{
    TableAttribute myAttribute = (TableAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(typeof(Cliente), typeof(TableAttribute));

    // versao pre C#6
    return myAttribute == null ? string.Empty: myAttribute.MyTableName;
    // ou entao
    // return myAttribute?.MyTableName ?? string.Empty;
}
```

(Veja [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/71s1zwct%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) um exemplo no MSDN e veja [aqui](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qPBwg9) uma demonstração no dotNetFiddle).

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o método GetCustomAttributes:

```
TableAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Cliente), false).OfType<TableAttribute>().FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

Lembre-se de tratar as possíveis exceções.

Referência: [Attribute.GetCustomAttributes Método](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.attribute.getcustomattributes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Boa! Muito obrigado.